# Check table size in cassandra historically

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've a Cassandra table (Cassandra version is 2.0) with terabytes of data, here is what the schema looks like

```
"my_table" (
  key ascii,
  timestamp bigint,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key), timestamp)
)
```

I'd like to delete some data, but before want to estimate how much disk space it will reclaim.

Unfortunately stats from JMX metrics are only available for last two weeks, so thats not very useful.

Is there any way to check how much space is used by certain set of data (for example where timestamp < 1000)?

I was wondering also if there is a way to check query result set size, so that I can do something like `select * from my_table where timestamp < 1000` and see how many bytes the result occupies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to see the size on disk from the data, it can be pretty far removed from the coordinator of the request and theres levels that impact it like compression and multiple sstables which would make it difficult.

Also be aware that issuing a delete will not immediately reduce disk space. C* does not delete data, the sstables are immutable and cannot be changed. Instead it writes a tombstone entry that after gc_grace_seconds will disappear. When sstables are being merged, the tombstone + data would combine to be just the tombstone.  After it is past the gc_grace_seconds the tombstone will no longer be copied during compaction.

The gc_grace is to prevent losing deletes in a distributed system, since until theres a repair (should be scheduled ~weekly) theres no absolute guarantee that the delete has been seen by all replicas. If a replica has not seen the delete and you remove the tombstone, the data can come back.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

Using `sstablemetadata` you can find tombstone drop times, minimum timestamp and maximum timestamp in the `mc-####-big-data.db` files.

Additionally if you're low on HDD space consider `nodetool cleanup`, `nodetool clearsnapshot` and then finally `nodetool repair`.

Comment: As a note, the nodetool clearsnapshot may get rid of your 'backups'.  These are created when you truncate and drop tables so that you can recover.  

So if you're looking for hard drive space they're safe to delete.